# Angular 7 issue with passing value to components html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying something very simple but I keep getting an error:

Here is the code:

app.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-{{myvalue}}">stuff here</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
myvalue: string;


ngOnInit() {
    this.myvalue('6');
}
```

For some reason it's giving me this error:

Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures.

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't call a string, it's not a function. `this.myvalue = '6';`

Comment: you also should use `[ngClass]='"`

Comment: Angular is not Knockout! :D

Comment: did you define myvalue a function? obviously not try to assign value rather than passing as a param. 

you can use ng-class for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

**app.component.html**

```
<div [ngClass]="myvalue">...</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
myvalue: string;
ngOnInit() {
    this.myvalue = 'col-md-'+'6'; //concatenate your value as string here
}
```

If you want to pass data using with `function`, you can achieve it by using this approach,

```
myvalue: string;
ngOnInit() {
  this.setValue('6');
}

setValue(val: string){
    this.myvalue = 'col-md-'+val; //concatenate your value as string here
}
```

I also recommend you to read this documentation, https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 1):

you have to assign value to string as this:

```
myvalue: string;


ngOnInit() {
    this.myvalue = 6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend @shadowman_93's solution. We have property binding for a reason. There's no reason to change CSS decorators in your component for this. It makes more sense to keep 'col-md' in your template, that way if you ever need to change it you will find it in an intuitive place, not in a string literal in your component. Thats just bad design.

Strings are not functions. You are setting your string as if you are calling a set function for it. Strings in Typescript work like strings in pretty much every other language, so

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myvalue = '6';
}
```

Comment: I think the point is, he is trying to undestand how [ngClass] property and function call's are works. Sometimes you need to explore  pros and cons or needs of your app by yourself. So I'm not pro consultant here, just trying to show anyone the way of doing someting. Methods/ways can be increased.